# A question on integers relatively prime to their Euler totien function

Tags: nt.number-theory

For the problem I am working on I have realised that some of the proofs could be slightly simplified if a certain number theoretic question has a positive solution. Now, the problem is in finite group theory, and unless the answer is really "immediate" I don't think that I intend to use number theoretic techniques. Nevertheless I am intrigued by the question and I would love to know the answer. Here it is.

Consider the set $X$ of natural numbers $n$ relatively prime to their Euler totien function $\varphi(n)$. It is important (I believe) to observe that, given $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the size of $\{x\in X\mid x\leq n\}$ is asymptotic to $an/\log\log\log n$ (for some absolute constant $a$).

Let $Y$ be a subset of $X$ containing all prime numbers. Suppose that, given $n$, the size of $\{y\in Y\mid y\leq n\}$ is asymptotic to $bn/\log n$ (for some absolute constant $b$). This is the whole information I have for $Y$.

Consider $Z$ the subset of $X$ consisting of all the elements $x\in X$ such that, for every divisor $m$ of $x$ with $m$ not being a prime, we have $m\notin Y$.

I am interested in the growth  of the size of $\{z\in Z\mid z\leq n\}$. Does it grow as $n/\log\log\log n$ or less?

Comment: Isn't $Z$ just equal to $X$? By definition, the elements of $Y$ are prime numbers, and so $m$ not being prime forces $m \not\in Y$.

Comment: @JeremyRouse: I read the condition as “$Y$ be a subset of $X$ containing all prime numbers, and possibly some other numbers”.

Comment: Yes, I have very little information on $Y$. I know that $Y$ is contained in $X$ and that it contains all prime numbers. Moreover I know that $Y$ is quite "small" compared to $X$. So, I am hoping that this will force $Z$ to be as "big" as $X$. (Answering to the clarification above: $Y$ can contain non prime numbers.)

Comment: It might clarify things to note that this is "happening inside S", where S is the set of squarefree numbers and has a natural semilattice structure on it. Z is just X intersect the complement of a join-ideal of S generated by those members of Y that are not primes.  If there are finitely many nonprime members of Y, it may be straightforward to show the ideal grows slowly.  It may also be possible to find a "sparse infinite cover" which would force Z to be much smaller than you hope.  Gerhard "This Mindset Worked Once Before" Paseman, 2015.07.17